# Image reload using glide when re open the app

Tags: java, android, image, android-glide

The image on the Firebase is loading through the glide. The first loading is successful, but there is a problem with the image not loading when you exit the app with the back and then run the application again.

The image is being loaded in Baseadapter. When the app is re-enabled, "onResourcesReady" is not being called.

```
if (convertView == null) {
            viewholder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

            viewholder.imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            viewholder.textDate = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_date);
            viewholder.textContents = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_contents);

            viewholder.imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, width));
            convertView.setTag(viewholder);
        } else {
            viewholder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        String date = itemList.get(position).getYear() +
                " / " +itemList.get(position).getMonth() +
                " / " + itemList.get(position).getDay();

        if (viewholder.imageView.getDrawable() == null) {
            Glide.with(context).clear(viewholder.imageView);
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(itemList.get(position).getImages())) {
            viewholder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        Log.d(TAG, TAG + " ///// uri : " + itemList.get(position).getImages());
        requestManager
                .load(itemList.get(position).getImages())
                .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onLoadFailed : " + e.getMessage());
                        Log.d(TAG, "isFirstResource : " + isFirstResource);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onRecousrceReady()");

                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .into(viewholder.imageView);
```

This code is part of getView(). This BaseAdapter is used in the ListView.

'RequestManager' is being delivered and used by MainActivity.

How can images always be loaded?

Is there any way to reset the glide? I'm having a hard time doing this because it doesn't look normal. Help me. ;(

Answer (score 0):

You can check your latest dependancy glide is also manage cashe.